# Gulp - Renaming a file extension

Tags: gulp

Scenario: I have two config files. Using `gulp-rename`, I like to rename them from `.config` to `config.disabled`.

```js
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
gulp.task("zzz_Remove-Useless-Files", function () {
    var files = [config.websiteRoot + "/App_config/ConnectionStrings.config", config.websiteRoot + "/App_config/RewriteRules.config"];
    return gulp.src(files).pipe(
        foreach(function (stream, file) {
            return gulp.src(file.path)
                .pipe(debug({ title: "Disabling " }))
                .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                    path.extname = ".config.disabled"
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(file.base))
                .pipe(debug({ title: "Stream is now " }));
        })
    );
});
```

Running this task DOES rename the file to `.config.disabled`; however, it does it by copying the original file. Like this

[image: config files]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gulp-rename` doesn't [remove the `src` files](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename/issues/34). In order to do that, this is what I had to:

```js
    var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');
    var del = require("del");
    gulp.task("zzz_Remove-Useless-Files", function () {
        var files = [config.websiteRoot + "/App_config/ConnectionStrings.config", config.websiteRoot + "/App_config/RewriteRules.config"];
        return gulp.src(files).pipe(
            foreach(function (stream, file) {
                return gulp.src(file.path)
                    .pipe(debug({ title: "Disabling " }))
                    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                        path.extname = ".config.disabled"
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(file.base))
                    .pipe(debug({ title: "Stream is now " }))
                    .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
            })
        );
    });
```